# Circular DeQueue implementation error

Tags: c++, data-structures

Basically a dynamic array, which has circular rotation when is full. You have access to every element and you can change it's value, however you can insert and remove only from both ends.(constant time). Most of the methods seem to be working fine, however at certain "push" numbers I get wrong output.
For example first input is `1,2,3` then I insert `4` at the end. Next output is: `2,3,4` However after I insert `5` at the end the output is `2, 3, 5`

I have no idea what is causing this. I am posting the entire source code below (atleast the functions which have to do with the tests where the error must hide). There is some documentation in the file and an example of the error in case I haven't explained things clearly.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename Object>
class ArrayVector {
private:
  int capacity; // capacity
  int sz; // number of elements
  Object*   a;
  int f; // start of the indexes
  int b; // end of the indexes
public:
  ArrayVector(int initCap);
  ~ArrayVector();

  int size() const { return sz; }
  bool isEmpty() const { return size() == 0; }
  Object elemAtRank(int r);
  void pushBack( const Object& e);
  void pushFront(const Object& e);
  void popBack();
  void popFront();
};

template <typename Object> // constructor
 ArrayVector<Object>::
ArrayVector(int initCap) {
  capacity = initCap;
  sz = 0;
  a  = new Object[capacity];
  f = 0;
  b = 0;
}

 template <typename Object> // gets the element at a certain rank
 Object ArrayVector<Object>:: elemAtRank(int r)
 {
     return a[(f + r) % sz]; // starting position in real array + r % number of elements
 }




template <typename Object>
 void ArrayVector<Object>:: pushBack( const Object& e)
 {
     if(sz == capacity && sz > 0) // if the array is full time to spin it
     {
         if(f == capacity){          // Handles the front.
           f = 0;             // if the front is equal to the capacity
                        // set it to zero, else increment
         }else{
           f++;
         }
         if(b == capacity){     //Handles the back
             b = 0;             //if the back is equal to the capacity
           //  cout<< "SC insert  "<< e << " at  "<< b  <<endl;
             a[b] = e;
         }else{                 // set it to zero, else increment
            a[b] = e;
           // cout<< "SC insert  "<< e << " at  "<< b  <<endl;
            b++;
         }
     }else{

        a[b] = e;
      //  cout<< "insert  "<< e << " at  "<< b  <<endl;
        b++;
         sz++;
     }

 }

 template <typename Object>
  void ArrayVector<Object>:: pushFront( const Object& e)
  {
      if(f == 0){
          f = capacity-1;
      }else{
          f--;
      }
      a[f] = e;
      if(sz< capacity)
          sz++;
  }

int main()
{
    // Fill array and print it
    cout << "Fill with numbers" << endl;
    ArrayVector<int> asd(3);
    asd.pushBack(1);
    asd.pushBack(2);
    asd.pushBack(3);
    for(int i =0; i < asd.size(); i++)
       cout << asd.elemAtRank(i) << endl;
    //Test if it spins
     cout << "BEGIN Spin TEST " << endl;
    asd.pushBack(4);
     cout << "First test is ok" << endl;
    for(int i =0; i < asd.size(); i++)
       cout << asd.elemAtRank(i) << endl;
    // here the error comes
    asd.pushBack(5);
     cout << "On the second iteration things crash and burn" << endl;
for(int i =0; i < asd.size(); i++)
       cout << asd.elemAtRank(i) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't going to be able to implement it as a vector and obtain constant time insertions at the ends.  When you insert at the front, you'd have to push all of the existing elements over by 1 (meaning you'd have to iterate the list and copy/move each of them).  The same with pushing from the back.  If you want constant time insertion, you need to use a list-style structure.

Comment: The manner of implementation is more of a circular buffer than a vector, though I am interested in what is causing the error.

Comment: Your current implementation is not a circular buffer.  It is very much a vector.  That is the source of the logic problem you have in your current code (I explained it a bit more in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to your insertion times not matching your desired requirements, your issue is here:

```
template <typename Object>
void ArrayVector<Object>:: pushFront( const Object& e)
{
    if(f == 0)
    {
        f = capacity-1;
    }
    else
    {
        f--;
    }
    a[f] = e; // problem lies here!

    if(sz < capacity)
        sz++;
}
```

You are figuring out where to do the insert, but you are not pushing the other elements around the vector; that is, you are just overwriting the element at the insertion point.  If you wanted to push it onto the front, you would need to copy the other elements over 1 position each and then do your insert.  A better solution (which would match your constant insertion time requirement) would be to implement it as a double-linked list.  Pushing onto the ends would simply require the following pseudo-code:

```
void push_front(const Object& o)
{
    if (size == capacity)
        l.pop_back();
    l.push_front(o);
}
```

If you really must use a contiguous memory block, you will not get constant-time insertion, but it would look like this:

```
// Assumptions:  0 is always the front, capacity-1 is always the maximum back
template <typename Object>
void ArrayVector<Object>:: pushFront( const Object& e)
{
    // assume capacity > 0, move all the elements to the right one slot
    for (int i = capacity - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        a[i] = a[i - 1];
    }

    a[0] = e;

    if(sz < capacity)
        sz++;
}
```